# PHP on Server 2003: Enabling PHP_APC.DLL creates Error

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, php

When trying to enable PHP_APC.DLL, PHP crashes returning invalid access to memory location. Any ideas?  I am running 5.2.12 in ISAPI mode.  Here is what I have enabled extension wise:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dbase.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fdf.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mhash.dll
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_msql.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_zip.dll
extension=php_win32service.dll
```

ultimately i'm trying to create a PHP based uploader with a progress bar.  From what I understand PHP_APC is the only way to do this.  If anyone could help me stabilize PHP_APC or know of another UL with progress bar method, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered disabling `PHP_APC.DLL`?

Answer (score 0):

Why APC ?

use wincache its design for windows,  using apc and crash every hour

For progress you can use extension for PHP

LIKe

http:// downloads.php.net/pierre/

Find

php_uploadprogress

More info

http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2009/03/09/upload-progress-meter-for-windows-the-next-take.html